# Add gesture recognizer to a blank label

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I have a custom table cell subclass that looks like this:

[image]

where "Date:" and "Hours:" are `UIButton`s and the other two parts are `UILabel`s.  I use the cell in several different files, programmatically adding the appropriate selectors.  For the `UILabel`s, I add it in the view controller's `cellForRowAt` method like this:

```
(cell as? DateHoursCell)?.dateLabel.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dateLabelTap)))
```

This works fine when the label has text, but sometimes the data I load has nil values and when that happens, tapping the label does nothing.  How can I make it so that they're still tappable even with no text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's your problem, but your label's size is probably becoming 0 when there's no text. I would define a fixed size for it, or even better, make a parent UIView with a fixed size, then add the label to it, and then add the gesture recognizer to the parent UIView.

Comment: Turned out I had set up the constraints wrong, fixing those gave it a fixed size and now it's working.